# JQuery + Ajax slider with the foreground loading content via Ajax AND the background moving as well!

Tags: jquery, ajax, slider

Any ideas on how to recreate this

http://elegantthemes.com/preview/Sky/

With the slider in the foreground loading content via Ajax (not just scrolling through different panels) and the background moving as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to plug my own content, but I wrote an article about something similar to this: http://www.webistrate.com/jquery-transitioning-ajax-content-into-view-with-animate/

Basically it uses Jquery to animate a div just off screen into view when the content has been loaded via AJAX.